# Escape character to stop TeXstudio non "to-do" comments

Tags: texstudio, comments

TeXstudio highlights comment lines that start with more than two capital letters as a "to-do" item.

- Is there a way of restricting the highlighting to lines starting with the following only?

`%TODO: Do something`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this can only be done if you would rewrite the language definition.

However, there the next release will contain an option to configure the comments to be highlighted.